# jqplot - easy way to change the axis label for a fixed size series

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

I have a stacked bar graph that will **always** have 12 bars, I have a feeling there should be an easy to to just label them "jan", "feb", ... (always in order too) Did some googling and still can't figure it out, help me out please.

and it would be best if I dont have to edit the data array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the "ticks" parameter for the axis:

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.ticks

```
axes: {
  xaxis: {
    ticks: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
  }
}
```

Comment: apparently you need this line for strings to work:          renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,